# How to achieve this effect?

Tags: android

I want to be able to create this effect as shown:

[image]

Comment: Use a ViewPager to display the images

Comment: Google keywords: `android coverflow`

Answer (score 0):

Use Recyclerview with below library its create you mentioned effect.

```
compile 'com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.1'
```

see this, https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager